# adding active class to multi level accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I have a multi level accordion but only missing the active class, only for the active/open panel, without changing anything else, any help?

**JS:**

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var $this = $(this);

if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
    $this.next().removeClass('show');
    $this.next().slideUp(350);
} else {
    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
    $this.next().toggleClass('show');
    $this.next().slideToggle(350);}
});
```

here is the CodePen: https://codepen.io/mozes22/pen/XxQEBp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a couple of changes to your js. - https://jsfiddle.net/LordJording/ftr4j0Ly/2/

```
$this.removeClass('is-active');
```

The line above removed the class if you are closing the current open accordion

```
$this.parent().parent().find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
$this.addClass('is-active');
```

The first line looks at all the siblings and tried to locate an already active element and removed the class `is-active`
The second line then adds an `is-active` class to the current item you are toggling

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
        $this.removeClass('is-active');
        $this.next().removeClass('show');
        $this.next().slideUp(350);
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
        $this.addClass('is-active');
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
        $this.next().toggleClass('show');
        $this.next().slideToggle(350);
    }
});
```

Then in your CSS you will need to style your toggle element if it has the class `is-active`

```
.toggle.is-active {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
}
```

I noticed in your codepen demo you are using inline styling on the nested accordion, you might want to remove this from being inline and use your linked stylesheet instead as it might cause issues with your styling.

Comment: dude, thank a lot, your solution was perfect and saved time, but still for the sub accordion I am facing same problem..

Comment: I think its due to your html having inline styling on the inner accordions. Looking in inspect element it all seems to work fine. Looks like you have accepted a working answer so its all good, and your sorted. - https://jsfiddle.net/LordJording/ftr4j0Ly/2/

Comment: yes, the answer was great, I am having the inline styling because the sub accordion **the multi level** must be having different color and I am working on it now, but still having some issues..

Comment: within your CSS if you add some styling to '.accordion li li .toggle' you will be able to style the sub accordion. See - https://jsfiddle.net/LordJording/ftr4j0Ly/5/

Answer (score 2):

Please check this code.

```html
<style>
 ul 
 {list-style: none;
 padding: 0;}

 ul .inner 
 {padding-left: 1em;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: none;}

 ul .inner.show {
 /*display: block;*/}

 ul li 
 {margin: 0.5em 0;}

 ul li a.toggle 
 {width: 100%;
 display: block;
 background: grey;
 color: #fefefe;
 padding: 0.75em;
 border-radius: 0.15em;
 transition: background 0.3s ease;
 text-decoration: none;}

 ul li a.toggle:after
 {content: '\002B';
 float: right;}

 ul li a.toggle:hover {
 background: yellow;}

 .modal-dialog {
 max-width: 70% !important;
 margin: auto;}
 
 .modal-content 
 {height: 500px; }
 
 .modal-body 
 {background-color: rgb(3, 119, 184);
 height: 250px;
 overflow-y: scroll;} 
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>


<ul class="accordion">
    <li>
        <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);"><b>- Technical for Sales People</b></a>
        <ul class="inner">test</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);"><b>- New to Car Sales Foundation</b></a>
        <ul class="inner">test2</ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".inner").hide();
$(".inner:first").show();   
$(".toggle").click(function(){  
if ($(this).is(".show"))
{
$(this).removeClass("show");
$(this).next(".inner").slideUp(400);
}
else
{
$(".inner").slideUp(400);
$(".toggle").removeClass("show");

$(this).addClass("current");
$(this).next(".inner").slideDown(400);
}
});
});
</script>
```